# Network in LXC not forwading through a bridge

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, routing, bridge, lxc

I've got an LXC container, on the host I've got a bridge between the LXC container and `eth0`.

The LXC container can ping it's Host `10.1.0.5`, but can't ping the gateway of `10.1.0.2`. The host is able to ping the gateway.

`tcpdump` on the interface created for the LXC container is sending the pings to the router and is getting a reply back. But a `tcpdump` within the container shows nothing. Furthermore, running `tcpdump` in the container hangs when you press ^C (20-40sec), that doesn't happen in the host.

Any ideas what I should look for here?

```
root@hadoop-jobtracker:~# ping 10.1.0.2 &
[1] 876
root@hadoop-jobtracker:~# PING 10.1.0.2 (10.1.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.


root@hadoop-jobtracker:~# tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
^C
::::20+ sec delay occurs here::::
05:56:34.835833 IP 10.1.0.35.ssh > 10.1.0.5.32990: Flags [P.], seq 2715418718:2715418910, ack 3505056160, win 196, options [nop,nop,TS val 1608155 ecr 1608151], length 192

1 packet captured
111 packets received by filter
80 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: never run tcpdump w/o '-n' you might be eaten alive by dns-hickups ;)

Comment: You enabled IPv4 forwarding with `sysctl`?